# Override fastfail in the dll to prevent whole app crash on STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN (0xc0000409)

Tags: c++, dll, crash

I use the C++ dll in the Delphi Application.
The dll is compiled with /GS-.
There is a bug in the dll causing crash of the whole appication with windows error `0xc0000409`

This error occurs in the dll, so I can't debug it. 
Is there any way to catch such exception so that I could just reload the dll or at least get a chance to properly shutdown the application?

Comment: start by testing the dll in a C++ program, check the exporting functions convention before switching to a Delphi program

Comment: @Landstalker thanks for your answer! I cant test the dll itself, I dont have its source codes neither debug build, Also I dont have a simple reproduce case to translate it to a c++ program

Comment: I meant, try to create a new VS C++ executable project, add `C++ dll` path as `addional lib directory` for this new project, try to load dll and call some functions. a bit like you do with your Delphi project ... You are not forced to have the source code of the DLL, a `.dll` a header `.h` are enough (if you do not know the signature of the function that you want to call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to catch the 0xc0000409 exception. [This is by design](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside/C0000409).

The rationale is that this is a security risk. The application is not in a state where it can safely proceed.

Comment: There used to be a hook, `_set_security_error_handler` but it's been removed. The only reasonable thing to do was to call `TerminateProcess`, and that was already the default behavior, so there was no added value.